# Cannot connect to any database in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2

Tags: database, netbeans, database-connection, netbeans-8

After I reinstalled my computer I could no longer connect to any database in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2, even the sample. It shows "Connecting to database, please wait..." but nothing ever happens. All the time there's just "Starting the Java DB Server". No errors. It just doesn't work. I can't even create my own database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used different version of jdk and it works.